# Getting exception randomly when trying to assign bitmap

Tags: c#, compact-framework

I have a C# application form that display an image for 3 seconds before closing and opening another form. The code is as follow:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SampleProgram
{
public partial class failureMessage : Form
{
    private Bitmap backgroundImage = null; // backgound image bitmap
    private System.Windows.Forms.Timer myTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
    private const string imagePath = @"/NandFlash/MsgRefused.png";

    // Constructor
    public failureMessage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.Height = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height;
        this.Width = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width;

        try
        {
            backgroundImage = new Bitmap(imagePath);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

        myTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(TimerEventProcessor);

        // Sets the timer interval to 3 seconds.
        myTimer.Interval = 3000;
        myTimer.Enabled = true;
    }

    #region Timer event
    // This is the method to run when the timer is raised. 
    private void TimerEventProcessor(Object myObject, EventArgs myEventArgs)
    {
        myTimer.Enabled = false;
        myTimer.Dispose();
        backgroundImage.Dispose();
        backgroundImage = null;

        Form1 reopenMainpage = new Form1();

        reopenMainpage.Show();
        this.Close();
    }
    #endregion

    #region Paint the background
    protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(backgroundImage, 0, 0);
    }
    #endregion
}
}
```

However, on random occasion, i keep getting the following exception:

```
System.Exception was unhandled
Message="Exception"
StackTrace:
Location: Microsoft.AGL.Common.MISC.HandleAr(PAL_ERROR ar)
Location: System.Drawing.Bitmap._InitFromMemoryStream(MemoryStream mstream)
Location: System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor(String filename)
Location: SampleProgram.failureMessage..ctor()
Location: SampleProgram.Form1.ReceivedMsg(Object sender, FingerPrintSensorEventArgs e)
Location: SG7000.device.WndProcModification.onFGSensorTriggered(FingerPrintSensorEventArgs e)
Location: SG7000.device.WndProcModification.MyWndProc(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
Location: Microsoft.AGL.Forms.EVL.EnterMainLoop(IntPtr hwnMain)
Location: System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form fm)
Location: SampleProgram.Program.Main()
```

Upon some researching, I suspect it might be that I didn't dispose the bitmap object or timer object before closing the form, but the error is still coming on random time. Is there something wrong with my implementation, or I forget to do something? Any advice is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Have you trie to look in http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/68d67019-4c14-45b0-b518-5fbc0523e667/the-dreaded-exception-microsoftaglcommonmischandlear-at

Comment: I just saw it, this is a tricky situation, it seems the main suggestion is to dispose of the objects, I did that exactly but the problem is still kicking in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stack trace shows that the exception occurs when initializing the Bitmap. A workaround would be not to throw the exception.

```
    try
    {
        backgroundImage = new Bitmap(imagePath);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Don't throw
    }
```

If you load the bitmap frequently I'd advice to move the picture to the resources and access it on your form from there.

Also, move the lines below to the Close event handler. Attach the handler to the Close event. This will make sure that everything is disposed when the form closes.

```
myTimer.Enabled = false;
myTimer.Dispose();
backgroundImage.Dispose();
backgroundImage = null;
```

Comment: I tested it, but the problem still exists. I am guessing part of it might be a problem with winCE.

Comment: Okay....I re-tested according to your suggestion, and it works. However, I also notice that I have a SoundPlayer object (which I didn't dispose) playing a sound everytime before I invoke this class, might play a part to this problem, I will continue checking. Meanwhile I consider this thread closed. Thanks.